# Is is possible to implement is_nothrow_assignable without compiler builtins?

Tags: boost, implementation, type-traits

MSVC and LLVM use the compiler built-in functions invariably. Boost also doesn't provide any possible implementation.

If it cannot be implemented perfectly, are there any approximate implementations to fall back? For example, take advantage of or modify the literally similar is_assignable and is_nothrow_move_assignable provided by Boost?